# Android Webb - Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, web-applications

My WebApp has started crashing on 8.5.2018.
Literally opens, shows the last data it had form the main screen and crashes within a second.

I didn't change the code etc.

Whats helps,  uninstall and re install google play services.

This is what a get from the google PlayStore Dev-Backend.

Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 21. Wait queue head age: 5510.3ms.)

```
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
      | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7536cfb8 self=0x559750ad80
      | sysTid=22359 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f88470fe8
      | state=S schedstat=( 1902426213 348727927 4903 ) utm=134 stm=56 core=5 HZ=100
      | stack=0x7fe4f4f000-0x7fe4f51000 stackSize=8MB
      | held mutexes=
      #00  pc 00000000000199c0  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
      #01  pc 0000000000067474  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL33__pthread_cond_timedwait_relativeP23pthread_cond_internal_tP15pthread_mutex_tPK8timespec+96)
      #02  pc 0000000000026d68  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (???)
      #03  pc 0000000000bee3b4  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_view_ThreadedRenderer_nSyncAndDrawFrame__J_3JI+168)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame (Native method)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:342)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:2461)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2094)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:860)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:672)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:608)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:846)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5441)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: I have a similar stacktrace for a crash in my Native app. I happens only on Android 6.0 according to reports gor from Google Developer Console. Did you find the cause of the issue? Any solution? Thanks